# Need XPath ends-with function

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I am having trouble getting an XPath function to work. I am supposed to pull only the entries in the XML file that the name of them ends with the letter 'z' and I cannot get it to work. I am xmllint to manipulate the file with the cat command.

`ends-with()` only works on XPath 2.0 and I'm pretty sure the server only has XPath 1.0 so I have tried entering this command:

```
cat //country/city[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('z') +1)]/name
```

but I keep getting an error, and I am not sure if I am writing it improperly or if it is not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath is missing the step of checking return value of `substring()` whether or not it is equals to the expected string ending value `"z"`. So the correct XPath would be :

```
//country[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('z') +1) = 'z']/@name
```

And since `-string-length('z') +1` equals to `0`, that part can be omitted to get a simpler XPath, similar to the one posted by [@Kirill Polishchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787016/kirill-polishchuk) in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399910/2998271).

Comment: This was it pretty much. I had to make a few changes but here was my final answer i got.

    cat //country/city[substring(normalize-space(name), string-length(normalize-space(name)) – string-length(‘z’)+1) = ‘z’]/name

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
//country[substring(@name, string-length(@name)) = 'z']
```

Comment: I need to use a normalize space i think. Any idea how to format that around the substring function?

Comment: @BMitrano825 Use it on all `@name` within `substring()` like `substring(normalize-space(@name), string-length(normalize-space(@name)))`